# $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} (\mathbb{Q}_p,\|\|_{p}) = (\mathbb{R},\|\|)$?

Tags: soft-question, p-adic-number-theory

Dealing with the $p$-adic numbers with their canonic metric $(\mathbb{Q}_p,\|\|_{p})$, one usually defines
$$(\mathbb{Q}_\infty,\|\|_{\infty}):= (\mathbb{R},\|\|). \tag{1}$$

While in the first instance this can be seen as barely a definition, there
is ample evidence that it is a very sensible, if not the only proper way to define things. Maybe the most notable evidence is

$$ \prod_{p\le\infty} \|\alpha\|_p = 1 \tag{2}$$
for any rational $\alpha$.

Now this suggests that there might be a way to carry out a limit operation such that (2) is the evaluation of a

$$ \lim_{q\rightarrow\infty} \prod_{p=2}^{q}\|\alpha\|_p = \prod_{p\le\infty} \|\alpha\|_p$$

and instead of $(1)$ it is much more 
$$\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty} (\mathbb{Q}_p,\|\|_{p}) = (\mathbb{R},\|\|),$$
which puzzles me a lot.

(Moreover one notes that the commonly found $(2)$ is not exactly very "clean" as well in dealing with a improper inequality involving the $\infty$ symbol.)

For example

1. when looking at the definition of the $p$-adic metric of a number $x=\frac{a}{b}p^{\nu_p(x)}$ (with the suitably chosen $a,b,p$ and $x\ne0$)
   $$ \|x\|_p:=p^{-\nu_p(x)}.$$ Is there any way to see how such a limit $p\rightarrow\infty$ could work here to get the normal Euklidian metric?
2. Another puzzle for me in this is that all the $p$-adic metrics are obviously discrete, while the Euclidian metric of is continuous. So how can this work when we have this $\lim_{p\rightarrow\infty}$?

It appears to me that this is related to an inverse limit construction of the reals from the $p$-adics, a topic which is discussed for example [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19809/completion-of-the-rationals-to-the-reals-as-an-inverse-limit-construction).

In summary the question is, if there is a limit construction possible, e.g. employing an inverse or a direct limit, for constructing $\mathbb{R}$ from the set of $\mathbb{Q}_p$?

Comment: What on earth do you mean by $\lim_{p\to\infty}$ here??

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: exactly the one which is implied in (2).

Comment: Nothing in (2) explains what you mean by $\lim_{p\to\infty}(Q_p,\|\|_p)$. Indeed (2) lacks the expression "$\lim_{p\to\infty}$".

Comment: Indeed, you need to clarify what you mean by $\lim_{p \to \infty}(\mathbb Q_p,||\;_\;||_p)$. What does it mean for a sequence of *distinct* metric spaces to converge to a given one ?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: See. if I could specify it exactly, I would not need to ask. My question is indeed equivalent to your question, though I see hints that it makes sense. To the second part, just replace $\infty$ by say $q$ and add $\lim_{q\rightarrow\infty}$. If you do not see the heuristic basis of my question, a simple counter argument would be appreciated.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown: Is my suspect correct, that it is not the missing definition of the limit you disagree with but its actually rather this part: "While in the first instance this can be seen as barely a definition, there is ample evidence that it is a very sensible, if not the only proper way to define things."?

Comment: I think $\infty$ is just because of the intuition. In my knowledge, limit is not well-defined for a collection of $p$-adic fields. It is like, thinking(not rigorously) about real number as extremely large prime number $p$-adic number in some step of construction.

Comment: Say you replace the set of primes with the set of whole numbers, and the symbol $\infty$ with $0$. Why would the identity $\displaystyle\prod_{k=0}^\infty a_k=1$ "suggest" either of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^n a_k=\prod_{k=0}^\infty a_k $ or $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n=a_0$? I can't parse your "heuristic" as anything beyond a non sequitor.

Comment: @anon: This is a good point, thank you! I mean my point was: Given you know all ${a_k}$ except one you can determine the rest, no matter which it is. And then so to say the only missing one which you cannot enumerate is the $k=\infty$ one. So they are all of the "same kind" since they add to one but when enumerating them you never get the one you miss, so that must be the  $\infty$ one.